# Can't see uploaded images to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, images

I am not able to view images uploaded by users with their questions on Stack Overflow. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you by chance at a place that blocks `stack.imgur.com`?

Comment: How is that duplicate "too localized"?  `imgur.com` is blocked for me too, that's why I knew to ask.

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers I pinged imgur.com and received all packets that were sent. 4 of 4

Comment: @user793468 If you actually go to imgur.com do you see the images?

Comment: @Juhana I do not. Its blocked

Comment: Well there's your problem.